# Kак правильно получить обратный ответ от сервера при оправки формы ajax

Tags: ajax, вывод, формы

Здравствуйте подскажите пожалуйста как правильно в файле php обработчике сделать обратный ответ на странице,это код отправки формы на сервер:

```js
<script type="text/JavaScript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#form").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
     url: "podpiski.php",
     type: "post",
     data: $("#form").serialize(),
     success: function(answer) {
      $("#answerlog").html("");
     }
    }).done(function() {
     $("#loadlog").fadeOut(400);
    });
   });
  });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вам на клиенте ничего не нужно от севера, кроме как подтверждения «все ок», просто возвращайте с севера `true` А на клиенте проверяйте ответ. Для этого в анонимной функции в  `.done`, вы должны добавить какой-то параметр, туда поместиться ответ с сервера.

Answer (score 0):

1. Данные формы лучше передавать в виде массива вместо `serialize()` лучше использовать `serializeArray()` если переменных несколько
2. Не используй `success` (устаревшую функцию) и `done` вместе.
3. Ответ от php скрипта будет просто `echo 'true';`
4. И наконец если ты хочешь вернуть данные со скрипта а не просто статус его выполнения стоит сменить метод передачи в аяксе добавив `dataType: 'JSON',` после `type: "post"` тогда и ответ и его обработка изменятся.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#form").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var form_data = $("#form").serializeArray(); //удобней сразу передать массив;
    $.ajax({
      url: "podpiski.php",
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "JSON",
      data: data
    }).done(function(res) {
      if (res.url) { // если url существует, воспринимаем как должное, выводим сообщение и перенаправляем
        alert(res.message);
        location.href = res.url;
      } else { // иначе что-то пошло не так и выводим для себя сообщение в консоль
        alert('Что-то пошло не так.');
        console.log(res.message');
      }
    }).fail(function(res) {
      console.log('fail');
    });
  });
});
```

```html
// а в php ответ стоит сделать таким образом (к примеру)
if ($result = mysql_query($query)) { // проверяем удалось ли выполнить sql запрос
  if (count($result)) { // если да, и строку вернули то:   
    echo json_encode(array(
      'url' => $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],
      'message' => 'Пользователь с данным email адрес уже подписан!'
    ));
  } else { // если ответ пустой, то:
    echo json_encode(array(
      'url' => $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],
      'message' => 'Некорректный email адрес!'
    ));
  }
} else { // если не удалось выполнить sql запрос, то:
  echo json_encode(array(
    'message' => 'Ошибка'
  ));
}
```

Comment: мне надо получить ответ от сервера :else{
   header("Location: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
   echo "<p>Пользователь с данным email адрес уже подписан!</p>";
  }
 }
 else{
  header("Location: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
  echo"<p>Некорректный email адрес!</p>";
 }

Comment: Я поправил код, в примере php написал как передать сообщение и url а в js уже можно вывести информацию различными способами.